# Setting the selected layer on a Leaflet/Mapbox L.Control.Layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a map with a few base layers. Users can choose the base layer and then save the map. After saving the map, the system loads it with the new base layer. That base layer should be selected in the `L.Control.Layers` control. However, there's no way in the [API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.9/l-control-layers/) to select a base layer.

Anyone knows a way  around this, or a different plug in?

---

UPDATE: Here is the code I use. `MapConfigs` has the ids in MapBox, and can create the map that `L.control.layers` requires.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map( components.mapDivId , MapConfigs.idFor(baseLayerName) );    
map.addControl( L.control.layers(
    MapConfigs.toBaseLayersControlMap(map)
).setPosition("topright"));
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not store references to all the base layers available in a hash, then use `addLayer` or `removeLayer` (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addlayer) as needed to programmatically select base layers?. Something like below.

```
var tileLayers = {light: L.tileLayer('lightUrl'),dark: L.tileLayer('darkUrl')}
```

Comment: Thanks - but that does not include the UI and the implementation for the IControl interface. If there's no available plug-in already implemented, then indeed the way you propose would be the way to go.

Comment: Well, there is no need for a plugin for the control, its already built into core. Init a map with `var map = L.map 'map', {zoomControl:false}`, then init a Layer Control with `var layersControl = new L.Control.Layers(tileLayers)`, then `map.addControl(layersControl)`

Comment: thanks @snkashis - but it's not working... the added layers control has the first layer marked, even though it is not the active base layer in the map.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post some of your code here so we can see   the flow as you have it?